# How to create new table with duplicated contacts

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to create sql procedure or function that need to find duplicate users in my users table (duplicate in case the users have the same email). I want to save the users in a new table like this:

```
id | user_id | duplicate_users
```

The duplicate_users will contain array of user id that have the same email like user_id
This is my main query but it's really bad because i get to many results.

```
SELECT  a.id user_id,
        a.email,
        b.id,
        dup_user_id
FROM    users a, 
        users b
WHERE   a.email = b.email
  AND   a.id != b.id
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What are you using. mssql, mysql,oracle etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by "array of users?" Do you mean storing a collection data type? A CSV list? The term "Array" does not really fit within the Oracle sphere.

Also, by nature of what you are asking you want the key to be the email, not one of the IDs otherwise you get each combination.

For example users a and b each have email "bob@inter.net". You query would have

a, bob@inter.net, b
b, bob@inter.net, a

And I think what you want is

bob@inter.net, (a,b)

Now, to make the field a CSV list of IDs you could use :

```
SELECT  email,         
        listagg(id,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) as list_of_ids        
FROM    users
GROUP BY email
```

If you want to store the ids in an oracle collection, I could steer you in that direction too.

EDIT: based on your comment.

OK, if you want the full results, then ammend to

```
SELECT  a.id as id
        a.email as email,         
        listagg(b.id,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) as list_of_ids        
FROM    users a, users b
where   a.email = b.email
and     a.id != b.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.email
```

So if users a, b, and c all share email bob@inter.net you will get:

a, bob@inter.net, "b,c"

b, bob@inter.net, "a,c"

c, bob@inter.net, "a,b"

If you want to drop the email from the query, then:

```
SELECT  a.id as id
        listagg(b.id,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) as list_of_ids        
FROM    users a, users b
where   a.email = b.email
and     a.id != b.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

Incidentally, if you are on an older version of Oracle that does not support the listagg string aggregation function, then you will be able to find an alternate solution here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php

I would suggest using the wm_concat() equivalent for Oracle 11.1 or 10, or one of the others for Oracle 9.

So, for Oracle 11.1 or 10, use:

```
SELECT  a.id as id
        a.email as email,         
        wm_concat(b.id) as list_of_ids        
FROM    users a, users b
where   a.email = b.email
and     a.id != b.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.email
```

Comment: csv list is good for me, the result should be contact_id,list of id's with the same email,

Comment: Updated my answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 email, 
 COUNT(email) AS occurrences
FROM 
 users
GROUP BY 
 email
HAVING ( COUNT(email) > 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY users.email ORDER BY users.email) RowNbr,
        users.id,
        users.email
    FROM
        users
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr>1
```

This will get you the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query 
what @vulkanino had posted is for your reference and you can use this query for your answer as follow --

```
select ID --* 
  from users
 where email in 
      (
         SELECT email
           FROM users
          GROUP BY email
         HAVING ( COUNT(email) > 1 )
      )
```

this query should give you list of id having email which are occupying by any other ID also , what I understood with your question.

please correct me if my understanding with your question is wrong..